# How are the aggregations calculated in Stack Overflow backend

Tags: discussion

How are all the aggregations done in the Stack Overflow application?

Stack Overflow [uses SQL Server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101918/which-database-does-stackoverflow-use-behind-the-scenes). I'm very interested in knowing how they perform all the heavy aggregations. It behaves quite good!

Do they use simple views, indexed views, custom implementation with triggers, are the calculations synchronous/asynchronous?

Comment: That might be something only an employee of the company should know.

Comment: What aggregations?

Comment: all aggregations: most of them are sums: reputation, viewed counter, star counter, tag counters, amount answers ... and aggregations used to sort questions, users, tags...